# Can Azure function read AAD user detail without having Application permission (Only delegate permission allowed by Org)

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

Azure function have below delegate permission

[image]

The code works when I use Application permission. But if I switch application permission to Delegate permission. I am able to accrue the access_token but when I try to read user details It gives me Authorization Access error.

```
   private async Task<IAuthenticator> GetTokenFromServer()
    {
        try
        {
            var request = new RestRequest()
                .AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                 .AddParameter("client_id", "**********")
                 .AddParameter("client_secret", "*******")
                 .AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials")
                .AddParameter("scope", "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");

            var tokenResponse = await new RestClient(TokenUrl).ExecutePostAsync<TokenResponse>(request);
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(tokenResponse.Content);
            string token = result.access_token;
            return new JwtAuthenticator(token);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new JwtAuthenticator("error");
        }
```

}

```
public async Task<UserProfile> FindUserByEmail(string email, TokenClient clientObj)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = new RestRequest("users")
                .AddQueryParameter("$filter", $"mail eq '{email}'");
            //.AddQueryParameter("$select", "userPrincipalName");
            var rest = new RestClient(GraphUrl)
            {
                Authenticator = await clientObj.GetToken(),
            };
            var response = await rest.ExecuteGetAsync(request);
            var userResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ODataResponse<UserProfile>>(response.Content);
            if (userResponse != null && userResponse.Value.Length > 0)
            {
                return new UserProfile
                {
                    Email = userResponse.Value[0].Email,
                    FirstName = userResponse.Value[0].FirstName,
                    LastName = userResponse.Value[0].LastName,
                    Office = userResponse.Value[0].Office,
                    Region = userResponse.Value[0].Region,
                    ServiceLine = userResponse.Value[0].ServiceLine
                };

            }
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Client credentials flow works only with **Application** permissions. If you want to read user details with Delegated permissions, you need to make use of **interactive** flow like authorization code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via Postman and got below results:***

I registered one Azure AD application and added **Delegated** API permissions same as you like below:

[image]

I generated **access token** using client credentials flow via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: <appID>
client_secret: <secret_value>
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used the above token to read user details, I got *Authorization Request Denied* **error** like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=mail eq 'sridevi.machavarapu1@gmail.com' &$select=mail,givenName,surname,officeLocation,country,userPrincipalName
```

**Response:**

[image]

> Delegated permissions only work with **Delegated** flows like authorization code flow that includes **user interaction**

You can make use of below **authorization request** to get **`code`** value like below:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?client_id=<appID>
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

When I ran the above request in browser, I got **`code`** successfully in address bar like this:

[image]

Now I generated **access token** using *Authorization code* flow via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id: <appID>
client_secret: <secret>
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
code: <code_from_above>
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this **token** to read user details, I got **results** successfully like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=mail eq 'sridevi.machavarapu1@gmail.com' &$select=mail,givenName,surname,officeLocation,country,userPrincipalName
```

**Response:**

[image]

In your case, change your flow from client credentials to **Delegated** flow like Authorization Code that involves user interaction which works for **Delegated** permissions.

**Reference:**  [Microsoft identity platform and OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)